# Limit each do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

If I have the following,

```
<% @feed.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.each do |feed| %> 

<% end %>
```

How can limit it to only show the 10 most recent results

Comment: Why don't you just sort first and then slice the array to get the first 10?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
<% @feed.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.first(10).each do |feed| %>
```

However, it's probably best to push this down into the model like this

```
<% @feed.recent(10).each do |feed| %>
```

And, in fact, if `@feed` comes out of a database, I'd push it down even further: it doesn't make sense to load a ton of unsorted feed entries out of the DB, then sort them and then throw most of them away. Better let the DB do the sorting and filtering.

See @Peer Allan's answer for how to do it in `ActiveRecord`. In `ARel` (IOW: Rails 3) it would probably be even simpler, something like

```
Feed.all.order('created_at DESC').take(10)
```

Comment: If I wanna use `@feed` twice: one to show 10, another to show all, is it better for me to limit it in view with `recent(10)`, then the next just normal for loop for `@feed`.

Answer (score 21):

[Array#first(n)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002164)

```
[1,2,3,4,5].first(3)
=> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 12):

I'd do it like this:

```
<% @array.limit(10).each do |a| %>
```

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the others (Jörg in particular); but if you still want to know how to limit the loop itself, `break` can be useful.

```
@array.each_with_index do |feed, i|
  break if i == 10;
  # ...
```

Comment: There are much better methods of limiting the number of displayed elements, than breaking the loop: `first` and `[]` operator work very well in such a scenario.

Comment: I don't know about "better", but other answers are certainly nicer, which I specifically point out. "Better" is very situational; I might point out that the methods you propose make a new array, while mine doesn't. The point is, since the other answers already focused on limiting the collection itself, I answered just the literal question, adding another option: presupposing the loop over the whole collection, how to only run in 10 times max. It's not a solution I'd choose unless I was pressed for time, as it does make the code uglier.

Comment: Yes it's matter of style mostly. But if there is a direct concept expressing the intent of a programmer (like `first`, `[]` and `order(...).take(10)` especially) I personally find it more appealing to use it.

Answer (score 6):

The created_at seems to indicate that you are using ActiveRecord in Rails to get set the @feed variable.  If that is the case you are better to do this work in SQL. Its far more efficient and easier to deal with.

```
@feed = Feed.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10)
```

Otherwise if you really want to use the view to do this you can use first or a range

```
<% @feed.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}[0..9].each do |feed| %> 
<% @feed.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.first(10).each do |feed| %>
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code will return 10 recent records.

```
@feed = @feed.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }.take(10)
```

[Array Reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

Comment: Awesome. This allows you to limit _after_ doing the sort. In my case, I'm sorting on the highest number of polymorphic associations. I can't write a query for it (don't know how!). This works nicely.